# when to use panel time-series regression vs seeming unrelated regression

Tags: r, dataset, panel-data

I am a bit confused on whether or not I have to use a fixed-effect panel time-series method or SUR (seemingly unrelated regression). To get a background of what I am trying to do, I have 10 panels of 25 weeks of data with four independent variables and one dependent variable and I am trying to find how these four independent variables effect the dependent variable. I am currently using R to do my analysis.

Comment: the description is confusing. can you put some equations and explain what you by _panel_?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what do you mean, you have 10 panels? Are they unrelated datasets? Does this mean that you have more than one dependent variable?

If you have only one dependent variable, you do not need to consider SUR.

If you have several time series, and assume that error terms may be correlated, take a look at seemingly unrelated time series equations.

http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1391754?uid=3737528&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106874145663